# How to use my icon image with glyphicon class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

HI I am using mvc 5 which is having bootstrap class integrated and i have to use glyphicons for my menus and i wanted to use my icon image as glyphicon so i want that without affecting predefined class of bootstrap i do the same with my icon images with new created css class in bootsrap.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what your looking for. You should really post an example but ill try and help here.

From the Bootstrap website:

> **Don't mix with other components** Icon classes cannot be directly
>   combined with other components. They should not be used along with
>   other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested and apply the
>   icon classes to the .
>
> **Only for use on empty elements** Icon classes should only be used on
>   elements that contain no text content and have no child elements.

Proper use:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="btn btn-warning">
    link text 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"/>
</a>
```

If you want to use a custom css class other than Bootstraps then creat a new css file all all your classes to it, even classes you want to override from bootstrap and then load that css file in the bundle file located in the App_Start directory. as shown Below.

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/YOURCUSTOMCSSGOESHERE.css  
                          ));
        }
    }
```